# How to store file in SQL Server using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to store File binary data in SQL server VARBINARY(MAX) column.

Below is my ruby code to store data

```
blobData = File.read(file_path)
query = "UPDATE SSAttachments SET blobData='#{blobData}' WHERE id=#{resp['id']}"
@client.execute(query);
```

I am getting below error on line `execute`

```
ArgumentError: string contains null byte
        from app/models/client.rb:211:in `execute'
```

I am using **TinyTds** rubygem to connect to SQL server.

The `blobData` has huge content some part of it looks this way

```
%PDF-1.6
%âãÏÓ
1 0 obj
<</Metadata 2 0 R/Pages 3 0 R/Type/Catalog>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<</Length 3718/Subtype/XML/Type/Metadata/Filter/Crypt>>stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.4-c005 78.150055, 2013/09/11-19:51:17        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/"
            xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/"


<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj
10 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length    1760>>stream
Äo\Áb[Tµ0ó#ZôdÜ—Ç¨WmÄP‘ÐL4‡åš *U1=Ÿy¬¢]«9ÞAà|oÎÝùÚFåÇ·Öf ¿àÙþòh¹Iž¥Þ_.ÖŸùži­?¯çõ<?A³¤j·m‘ÿKçéIU-`.ÕÊ|!ÏÐ=¦„8‚øÊ«XXF‘b¢—3Ÿ
    9—jóè—]‚Ïj²àk4h?¼õÀ¤Óa/zf¸  ¸M»™Ù¥  ”?êVò!o~cöì©Ç¹caþßyKnkf`äY¿‰a¯Í+ò†Y~tõéÝ‚.oYí/œ¬|áÀV<‰°‚ª‘&Þ(„•G·µÇª
```

Comment: can you check value of blobData variable before a query?

Comment: I have updated value of blobData.